# Go app cannot connect over websocket inside docker-compose

Tags: docker, go, websocket, docker-compose, docker-network

So I have a very simple app written in Go, that needs to connect to the database over a websocket. This works fine when I run the database inside a container and expose the required ports via `docker run -d -p 8182:8182 tinkerpop/gremlin-server`, with the app locally pointing at localhost:8182.

However I now want to run both inside containers via compose for CI, and my app cannot find the database. I've tried using docker hostnames, IP addresses, and listening on 0.0.0.0 to no avail. Currently my compose looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: tinkerpop/gremlin-server
    hostname: gremlin
    ports:
      - 8182:8182
  server:
    build: .
    environment:
      ORBITAL_DB_ADDRESS: "ws://gremlin:8182"
    ports:
    - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - db
```

However I seem to only get the following message from my app container:  `dial tcp: lookup gremlin on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host`.

This is despite my app set to ListenAndServe on 0.0.0.0:

```
err := http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf("0.0.0.0:%d", conf.Service.Port), nil)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of Go lang, but normally the database service (`db` here) should be provided as the database host. So, try to add that and check if it works.

Comment: @AtulKhanduri already tried that im afraid: I get `read tcp 172.19.0.3:44860->172.19.0.2:8182: i/o timeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to work this out. Turns out the Dockerfile for the 3rd party container was already set to `EXPOSE 8182`, and I was additionally mapping the host:container port in compose with:

```
ports:
  - 8182:8182
```

For some reason this was causing a timeout when trying to reach `ws://db:8182` and when I removed the port mapping in compose this resolved itself and became available.

My final docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: tinkerpop/gremlin-server
  server:
    build: app
    environment:
      ORBITAL_DB_ADDRESS: ws://db:8182
    ports:
    - 5000:5000
```

I can't explain why exactly this happens but would be interested if anyone else can explain in more technical detail what was going on here as it seems the `EXPOSE` in the dockerfile, and `ports` in compose were at odds with each other.

Comment: I faced the exact same issue and removing ports from docker composed helped. Not sure what is causing the issue neither...

Answer (score 0):

From your original post 3 things come to mind to try:

1. fix connection string

   replace `ws://gremlin:8182` to `ws://db:8182`
2. make sure db is up and running (`depends_on` doesn't guarantee that)

   easy debug way is to first run db

   ```sh
   $ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up db
   ```

   wait when it'll ready and then in separate console run server

   ```
   $ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up server
   ```
3. other configs

   If there are other configs where you set connection to database don't forget to put there host which is available under current network

   - when server up locally and db in docker then both available under `localhost`
   - when both run in docker-compose then hosts are `db` and `server` accordingly)

Comment: According to the docker-compose docs `hostname` is a supported parameter along with `domainname`: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir

Comment: You're right, my bad. I've deleted mistaken statement

Comment: @jhole89 i revised my answer, probably this will help. pls let my know if it doesn't

Comment: see my comment on the OP, I have already tried this unfortunately. In terms of the db being up, i am already handling this inside the app with a timed wait & retry.

Comment: does your app available on github? could you share with a link? I'll try to launch locally